# How can I get my syncadapter account to appear in Google Contacts app?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to get my android application's custom contacts to appear in Google's (latest) Contacts app from the playstore but am unable to get my user's account to appear in the sideshelf drawer of the Contacts app quick account switcher list. What do I need to do to get my account to appear in this list?

I have implemented the following:

My Android Manifest has the following entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.contactsynctest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_KEYBOARD"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.contactsynctest.ContactSyncActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.test.contactsynctest.TestSyncService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter_contacts"/>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.test.contactsynctest.AuthenticatorService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator"/>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

AccountAuthenticator

```
package com.test.contactsynctest;

import android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator;
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.NetworkErrorException;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class AccountAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {

    private static boolean removalAllowed = false;
    private Context context;

    public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.test.contactsynctest";
    public static final String USERID = "bob@test.com";

    public AccountAuthenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                             String accountType, String authTokenType,
                             String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options)
            throws NetworkErrorException {

        Account account = new Account(USERID, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        AccountManager.get(context).addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null);

        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, 1);
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        b.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        return b;
    }

   // The following are required but all return null or a default value

    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                               Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options)
            throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                              Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse arg0,
                                     Account arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                                    Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getAccountRemovalAllowed(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, removalAllowed);
        return b;
    }
}
```

AuthenticatorService

```
package com.test.contactsynctest;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class AuthenticatorService extends Service {

    private static AccountAuthenticator auth = null;

    public AuthenticatorService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT)) {
            if (auth == null) {
                auth = new AccountAuthenticator(this);
            }
            return auth.getIBinder();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

ContactSyncActivity

```
package com.test.contactsynctest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.OperationApplicationException;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ContactSyncActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_export);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                writeContact("Sally" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(), "123-456-789");
                Toast.makeText(ContactSyncActivity.this, "Contact created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, 2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contacts_export, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            AccountManager.get(this).addAccount(AccountAuthenticator.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(ContactSyncActivity.this, "Account registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void writeContact(String displayName, String number) {
        ArrayList contentProviderOperations = new ArrayList();
        //insert raw contact using RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
        contentProviderOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountAuthenticator.ACCOUNT_TYPE).withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, AccountAuthenticator.USERID).build());
        //insert contact display name using Data.CONTENT_URI
        contentProviderOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName).build());
        //insert mobile number using Data.CONTENT_URI
        contentProviderOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number).withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());
        try {
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().
                    applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, contentProviderOperations);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

TestSyncService

```
package com.test.contactsynctest;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter;
import android.content.ContentProviderClient;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SyncResult;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class TestSyncService extends Service {

    private static SyncAdapterImpl syncAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        if (syncAdapter == null) {
            syncAdapter = new SyncAdapterImpl(this);
        }
        return syncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }

    private static class SyncAdapterImpl extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

        public SyncAdapterImpl(Context context) {
            super(context, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extra, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult result) {
            // nothing needed here for this test
        }

    }
}
```

In my xml directory I have the following files

account-authenticator

syncadapter_contacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:accountType="com.test.contactsynctest"
              android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
              android:supportsUploading="true"
    />
```

account_preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I've tested a few other apps and see inconsistent behavior between Android 7 and Android 8 - such as, the yahoo app on Android 7.x does NOT appear in the left drawer quick account switcher list, while the exact same version of the yahoo app and the Contacts app running on Android 8.0 does show the yahoo account in the list. All gmail accounts appear to show up in the Contacts app account switcher at all times, but other accounts vary.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the list of accounts in the contacts app you want to appear in?

Comment: I don't seem to have the ability to post images but if you look at the playstore listing for [Google Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts&hl=en) then look at their photos there is one titled "View your contacts by account" that's where I'm expecting to see my account appear.

Comment: I would expect only Google accounts to appear in the account switcher, as with all Google apps, the sidebar Google implements usually let's you switch between your different Google accounts, I've never seen any other account there.

Comment: I've seen several others including Yahoo mail so it's definitely not restricted to Google accounts.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of this sidebar showing the yahoo email? you can create a google account using a yahoo email, maybe that's what you're seeing?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post screenshots, but the yahoo account I see is appearing after I install and configure the Yahoo mail app.

Comment: interesting... i have many sources for contacts on my device, but I only see my 2 google accounts appearing in the siderbar. maybe they have a whitelist of specific contact sources they allow showing there...